# access Session variable from aspx into UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Session["Name"] in my aspx.cs file
how to access it from the UserControl codebehind on the same page

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
string name= HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"].ToString();
```

or

```
string name=Session["Name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object from that control.

Answer (score 0):

Without see a little bit of the code, it would be hard to tell.

- Maybe the session is timing out
- Is there an error happing that causes the session state to be clear, or an logout
- Modifying the web.config or many files can cause the application to restart.

Finally I have to ask:
- Is session disabled in some way? Does it work between other pages? Maybe it is disabled for Ajax requests?
- Is is maybe a magic string error.

Personally, to avoid magic string errors, I use a Session Wrapper:

```
/// <summary>
///     The session manager
/// </summary>

public sealed class SessionManager 
{
    #region ISessionManager Members

    /// <summary>
    ///     Clears the session.
    /// </summary>
    public void ClearSession()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon(); //Abandon ends the entire session (the user gets a new SessionId)
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the current employe.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The current employe.</value>
    public EmployeDto CurrentEmploye
    {
        get { return Get<EmployeDto>(); }
        set { Add(value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The parameters.</value>
    public IList<ParameterDto> Parameters
    {
        get { return Get<List<ParameterDto>>() ?? new List<ParameterDto>(); }
        set { Add(value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">key</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.</exception>
    public static bool Add<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string key = null)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;

        if (current == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (current.Session.Mode == SessionStateMode.Off)
        {
            throw new Exception("Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.");
        }

        current.Session.Add(key, value);

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <returns>``0.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">key</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.</exception>
    public static T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string key = null) where T : class
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;

        if (current.Session.Mode == SessionStateMode.Off)
        {
            throw new Exception("Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.");
        }

        return current.Session[key] as T;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">key</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.</exception>
    public static bool Get([CallerMemberName] string key = null)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;

        if (current.Session.Mode == SessionStateMode.Off)
        {
            throw new Exception("Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.");
        }
        bool result = false;
        bool.TryParse(current.Session[key].ToString(), out result);
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Removes the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">key</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.</exception>
    public static bool Remove(string key)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;

        if (current == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (current.Session.Mode == SessionStateMode.Off)
        {
            throw new Exception("Session elements cannot be added when session is disabled.");
        }

        current.Session.Remove(key);

        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My example uses reflection to define the key name as the same as the property name, but you can use constants instead. It also checks if the Session is disabled, which might help in debugging your case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as well:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"]
```